# For contributors, is it necessary to fork a project and raise a pull request OR is it sufficient to create a new branch and raise a pull request?

Tags: git

I am new to GIT and want to understand how to collaborate with remote GIT repository projects.

I am reading that - 1st I need to fork the project which is equivalent to duplicating the project but as a separate repository and then when I am done making changes, I need to raise a pull request to merge changes from the forked repo into the original repo.

Why is the following not recommended?: Instead of forking, I clone the repo. Then create a feature branch, make code changes, and push changes to the feature branch. Then raise a pull request from the feature branch into the master branch.

Comment: Many projects don't allow random people to push commits to them.

Comment: The short answer is "it depends" (on the project and how freely they, whoever "they" are that control the project on GitHub, give write access to *you*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you will most likely not have permissions on the project to create branches, as you are someone outside the project.

However consider a typical enterprise/organization, in that case some orgs do use branches called feature branches or bugfix branches which you create and then create  PR to get them merged.

Here is one model that is followed : https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

You should also look at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows.

Comment: can you give me an example of a github project that allows to create branches and one that does not?